# Dynamic data in barchart not working properly javaFX

Tags: java, database, javafx, bar-chart, dynamic-data

I am trying to load data from a result set but when the chart is displayed some of the bars are missing.

Following is my code:

```
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        XYChart.Series<String, Double> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString(1);
            Double no = rs.getDouble(2);
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(name, no));
            barchart1.getData().add(series);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you adding the same series multiple times???

Comment: I think that you need to replace the line `barchart1.getData().add(series);` outside of the while loop.

Comment: @ShekkarRaee But if I do that, the data will be added in a single series.

Comment: @fabian No I am not adding the same series again and again. I am using this condition while (rs.next()) to iterate the result set and then each time different data is added in the series using series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(name, no));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new series for each row-data,

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
     String name = rs.getString(1);
     Double no = rs.getDouble(2);
     XYChart.Series<String, Double> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
     series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(name, no));
     barchart1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count>0) {// This means array has atleast one value stored
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
      amount = Double.parseDouble(categs[i].replaceAll(",", ""));
      Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<String,Number>();
      series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("", amount));
      categoChart.getData().add(series1);
      
    }//END for loop 
}//END if(count>0)
```

Comment: This worked for me when I was displaying data on a bar chart from a dynamic array.

Comment: please edit and add details to your answer (vs commenting it :)

Comment: btw: a) the if is not needed, the loop condition takes care of zero b) the loop index should be local to the loop (vs. re-using some external i)